# Beginner Configuring Spring without XML

Tags: java, spring

I'm reasonably familiar with Java and Eclipse and I thought I'd learn something about Spring and how to configure Spring without XML.  Right now when I try running, I get the exception

```
May 28, 2012 8:08:33 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@173e55db: startup date [Mon May 28 08:08:33 PDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: MessageConfig
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:346)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:222)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:620)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)
```

My classes are very simple:

```
public class SpringMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MessageConfig.class);
        DefaultMessage dmsg = context.getBean("defaultMessage", DefaultMessage.class);
        System.out.println(dmsg);
        }
    }

@Configuration
public class MessageConfig {
    @Bean
    public DefaultMessage defaultMessage() { return new DefaultMessage(); }
}

public class DefaultMessage {
    public DefaultMessage() {}

    private String message = "Spring is here.";

    public String getMessage() { return message; }

    public void setMessage(String message) { this.message = message; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("DefaultMessage[%s]", message);
    }
}
```

I've added nearly any jar file that seems relevant.  My classpath:

```
org.springframework.beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.jms-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.orm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.test-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.transaction-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
org.springframework.web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
cglib-2.2.2.jar
asm-4.0.jar
commons-codec.jar
ivy.jar
jets3t.jar
commons-httpclient.jar
```

So what am I missing?  Why is it unable to "load configuration class MessageConfig"?  I'm using jre7 and spring 3.1.1.

Thanks for any suggestions!

[EDIT]

JigarJoshi suggested I add the rest of the call stack.  Here it is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class net.sf.cglib.core.DebuggingClassWriter overrides final method visit.(IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)V
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.<init>(AbstractClassGenerator.java:38)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.<init>(KeyFactory.java:127)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:112)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:108)
at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:104)
at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:69)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.newEnhancer(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:136)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer.enhance(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:109)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhanceConfigurationClasses(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:336)
```

Comment: Could you please add the root cause of exception stacktrace ?

Comment: Plus I recommend against including what are essentially random libraries.

Comment: @JigarJoshi: Not sure what you mean.  When I try to get an instance of AnnotationConfigApplicationContext, I get the crash.

I agree with Dave Newton.  I started out with a hand-full of libraries and have added more and more in vain attempts to kill the exception.

Comment: @Russ Jigar is asking for the continuation of the stack trace. What appears after `at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:73)` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully created one web application without any xml configuration. I suggest you to do the following in your **MessageConfig** class.

1. Put `@EnableWebMvc` annotation defines that this class holds the Spring Framework's MVC configurations.
2. `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` that will let you override some useful functions like `addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)`

According to me you lack these points.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.